# Expand a collapse div without making any effect on navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a navbar, a collapse div and a table in a div. I want to click in the tr and the collapse div will appear.
However, Although I have made the div expand, the structure of the page is broken too: When the div appear, the table and the navbar will both narrow. I just want only the div that has table will narrow.
How can I solve this?

The structure I have build in html file:

```
<nav></nav>
<div class="row>
   <div class="col-9">
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
               </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td> 
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
   <div class="col-3 collapse">
        <div class="container"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have upload some int fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3b612srg/

Comment: please mention code on fiddle. we can fix it.

Comment: Okay. I have uploaded it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found on every site but nothing useful. And then I found that I can write typescript or javascript to set the class "collapse" disappear. May be that would be easier